# Обозначить несколько переменных в цикле Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть несколько последовательных функций, которые выполняются друг за другом.

`y1= df1['A']
x1 = df1[['B','C']]
x1= add_constant(x1,has_constant='add')
logit1 = Logit(y1,x1)
res1 = logit1.fit(method='bfgs')
me1 = res1.get_margeff(at='mean').summary()`

Мне необходимо проделать данные операции N количество раз, не хочется тупо переписывать, поэтому как-нибудь можно в цикле это все обозначить, например мне нужно 5 раз , т.е. во второй итерации будет:

`y2= df2['A']
...
me2 = res2.get_margeff(at='mean').summary()`

Потом третий, четвертый и в конце соответственно :

`y5= df5['A']
...
me5 = res5.get_margeff(at='mean').summary()`

Comment: для этого в языках программирования придумали функции, списки, словари и т.д. ;)

Comment: Ну вот не получается у меня(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните все расчеты в функцию, которая возвращает словарь:

```
def f(df):
    res = {}
    res["y"] = df['A']
    res["x"] = df[['B','C']]
    res["x"] = add_constant(res["x"], has_constant='add')
    res["logit"] = Logit(res["y"], res["x"])
    res["res"] = res["logit"].fit(method='bfgs')
    res["me"] = res["res"].get_margeff(at='mean').summary()
    return res
```

Все результаты сохраняем в словарь:

```
all_res = {i:f(df) for i,df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], 1)}
```

далее можно обращаться к результатам по ключам-индексам:

```
res1 = all_res[1]
res2 = all_res[2]
...
res5 = all_res[5]
```

и внутри результатов по ключам:

```
res1["x"]
res1["y"]
...
res1["res"]
res1["me"]
```

Comment: `res["res"] = logit1.fit(method='bfgs')` почему `logit1` ?

Comment: @Max52, исправил...

Comment: Отличное решение , благодарю